# htaccess redirect page without changing the url

Tags: .htaccess

Can .htaccess redirect a user without changing the url they typed in?

```
http://example.com/sample1.php
http://example.com/sample2.php#anchor
http://example.com/sample3.php?a=1#anchor
# All 3 files open the file main.php but the URL remains the same
```

Comment: are you using apache and have mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer but I'm cautious as to its security implications. Is putting this code in .htaccess a possible security hole:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/sample1.php [OR]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/sample2.php
RewriteRule   ^.*  /main.php [L]
```

Does this pose a threat or is it ok since I explicitly wrote down that only sample1.php and sample2.php will be redirected?